# How to find block level or disk level changes between two versions of the same file?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, file, filesystems

I'm developing a backup application for Windows OS. First I take a full backup and copy the entire file to the backup media. Next, while taking incremental backup, I need to find only the changes that have been made to the file after the previous full backup was taken. For this purpose, I need to determine the block level or disk level changes between two versions of the same file. I checked about FileSystemWatcher https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx class, but it only notifies me when a change has been done. It doesn't provide me the block level changes of the file. Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Comment: This may be of interest to you: http://www.daemonology.net/bsdiff/

Comment: Most files (office documents, images, videos etc) are not modified in-place but when saved a new temporary file is created, written to, then the old file deleted and the new file renamed.  Only record based applications like databases overwrite files in place.

Comment: It's probably not worth the effort.  Imagine a weekly (or even monthly) full backup with incremental backups once or twice a day.  For every single file that has changed for any incremental backup, you'll have to go back to the last full backup, copy the old version of the file from that backup to some working space and then apply the changes to that copy from each and every incremental backup made after the full backup - and then compare the recreated file's contents to the one you're trying to back up in order to find the new differences.  That will at the least *triple* backup IO needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to track all write operations (IRPs going to the filesystem) before they happen and right after they are performed with successful result. This is done with help of the filesystem filter driver. You can create one yourself in C, or you can use our CallbackFilter product, which includes a driver and user-mode APIs for .NET, C++ and Delphi.